# Transforming an array to object

Tags: javascript

How would I approach a task of transforming an array of arrays of arrays into an array of objects using javascript? E.g.

```
[
     [
          [a,b],[c,d],[e,f]
     ],
     [
          [g,h],[i,j],[k,l]
     ]
]
```

--->

```
[
     {a:b, c:d, e:f}, {g:h, i:j, k:l}
]
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `Array.prototype.reduce` as a starting point.

Comment: I'd make an object with some variables in it that are the kind of arrays that you need. Then make copies of the object into an array.

Comment: You do realize that ['a','b'] are two values: [0] = 'a' and [1] = 'b' and {'a':'b'} is this 'a' = 'b', right?

Comment: How about `let maps = array.map(array => new Map(array))`?

Comment: Your question title is not very good... In JavaScript, an array is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**functional data transformation with `map` and `reduce`**

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve the desired data shape

```js
const data = [
  [ ['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3] ],
  [ ['d', 4], ['e', 5], ['f', 6] ]
]

const data2 = data.map(pairs =>
  pairs.reduce((obj, [k,v]) =>
    Object.assign(obj, { [k]: v }), {}))
    
console.log(data2)
// [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 } ]
```

---

**generic functions**

The above transformation is cognitively dense and can be decomposed into two helpful functions – these two functions `mapReducer` and `pair2obj` are generic enough that we can easily reuse them in other parts of our program

```js
const mapReducer = (f, g) =>
  (acc, x) => f (acc, g (x))

const pair2obj = ([x, y]) =>
  ({ [x]: y })

const data = [
  [ ['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3] ],
  [ ['d', 4], ['e', 5], ['f', 6] ]
]

const data2 = data.map (pairs =>
  pairs.reduce(mapReducer(Object.assign, pair2obj), {}))

console.log(data2)
// [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 } ]
```

---

**native `Map`**

If you can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects in your program, this is probably better because your data is already in the format that the `Map` constructor accepts

```js
const data = [
  [
    ['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]
  ],
  [
    ['d',4],['e',5],['f',6]
  ]
]

const data2 = data.map(pairs => new Map(pairs))

console.log(data2[0].get('a')) // 1
console.log(data2[0].get('b')) // 2
console.log(data2[0].get('c')) // 3
console.log(data2[1].get('d')) // 4
console.log(data2[1].get('e')) // 5
console.log(data2[1].get('f')) // 6
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't think about expanding the pairs in the function definition.

Comment: @fubar destructuring can really help with readability in a lot of cases ^_^